# Value has been changed in method

Tags: go

I'm solving a [problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/combinations) in leetcode using recursion.
But, the value which is used as a parameter is changed in the method.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func makeCmbs(cmbs [][]int, nums []int, remains []int, k int) [][]int {
    fmt.Println("==", cmbs, nums, remains, k) // (2)
    if k == 0 {
        cmbs = append(cmbs, nums)
        fmt.Println("!", nums, cmbs)
        return cmbs
    }

    for i, num := range remains {
        fmt.Printf("-[%d] num:%d cmbs:%v remains:%v\n", i, num, cmbs, remains) // (1) cmbs here is [[1,2,3,4]]
        cmbs = makeCmbs(cmbs, append(nums, num), remains[i+1:], k-1) // cmbs in makeCmbs method is [[1,2,3,5]] ???
        fmt.Printf("+[%d] num:%d cmbs:%v\n", i, num, cmbs)
    }

    return cmbs
}

func combine(n int, k int) [][]int {
    remains := make([]int, n)
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        remains[i] = i + 1
    }

    return makeCmbs([][]int{}, []int{}, remains, k)
}

func main() {
    combine(5, 4)
}
```

Bellow is its beginning of output.

```
== [] [] [1 2 3 4 5] 4
-[0] num:1 cmbs:[] remains:[1 2 3 4 5]
== [] [1] [2 3 4 5] 3
-[0] num:2 cmbs:[] remains:[2 3 4 5]
== [] [1 2] [3 4 5] 2
-[0] num:3 cmbs:[] remains:[3 4 5]
== [] [1 2 3] [4 5] 1
-[0] num:4 cmbs:[] remains:[4 5]
== [] [1 2 3 4] [5] 0
! [1 2 3 4] [[1 2 3 4]]
+[0] num:4 cmbs:[[1 2 3 4]]
-[1] num:5 cmbs:[[1 2 3 4]] remains:[4 5] <---- cmbs is [[1 2 3 4]]
== [[1 2 3 5]] [1 2 3 5] [] 0             <---- why [[1 2 3 5]] ???
```

As you can see those last two lines, cmbs [[1 2 3 4]] became [[1 2 3 5]].
Could anybody please give me a clue why cmbs value is changed in makeCmbs method?

Comment: That's how slices work. A slice is a view into an array; when you pass a slice to a function, both the function and the caller have slices using the same backing array. See https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let start with recursion last recursive loop of calling `makeCmbs`

```
cmbs = makeCmbs(cmbs, append(nums, num), remains[i+1:], k-1)
```

As remains[i+1:] where the value of i at last loop will be the highest i.e

```
i = len(remains-1)
```

So it means it means `i+1` is two (2) greater then `len(remains-1)` that is why `remain[i+1]` will be empty `array ([])` for first two last recusrive rounds.

This is how it works. I hope I made it to the imaginative height of this problem.

**UPDATE:**

For the first time when `k=0`

```
start of function: num:[1 2 3 4] cmbs:[] remains:[5], k:0
```

So `if k=0` condition is `true`

```
    if k == 0 {
        cmbs = append(cmbs, nums)
        fmt.Printf("in side if: num:%d cmbs:%v k:%v\n", nums, cmbs, k)
        return cmbs
    }
```

that is the first return of recursion

as cmbs = [] and nums = [1 2 3 4]

```
cmbs = append(cmbs, nums)
```

Now retuned value is cmb from if condition is [[1 2 3 4]] to the for loop this line

```
cmbs = makeCmbs(cmbs, append(nums, num), remains[i+1:], k-1)
```

and here loop ends so it also return the same

```
 [[1 2 3 4]]
```

But at before that recursion nums was append of nums+num that is `[1 2 3 5]` so that is why when it return back in the second last recursion at the same for loop call cmbs hold `[1 2 3 5]`.

It is indeed a difficult question to image but can be solved easily with a debugger.

Comment: I think you are answering why remains become empty, but I'm asking why cmbs value has been change inside the method without any touch.

Comment: please have a look at my explanation after UPDATE. I hope it will answer your question.